# How to pass a function object to a Polymer element from javascript

Tags: javascript, polymer

I tried converting function to a string and pass it as below:

```
var myfunc = function (name) {
    alert('It works!' +name);
}

var as_string = myfunc.toString();

var contentHtml = "<my-element post='{\"value\":\"" + target.value.toString() + "\",\"update\":\"" + as_string + "\"}'></my-element>"
```

But it is not converting it into string properly. When I checked in dev tools
It appeared as below:

```
<my-element style="z-index:2998; width:700px;" post="{"value":"USUNCLM","update":"function (name) {
                    alert("It works!' +name); }"}'></my-element>
```

Converting to a function is working in JS Fiddle attached here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kavyapenujuru/L0m95396/

Is there any other way to pass a function to Polymer element ?
Or any other ways to improve my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Polymer working example: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/W0j964CFdJpAdVXjhNsp?p=preview)

Define the JavaScript object in the parent element:

```
 domReady: function() {
        // Animal properties and method encapsulation
        this.animal = {
          type: "Invertebrates", // Default value of properties
          displayType : function(){  // Method which will display type of Animal
            console.log(this.type);
            alert(this.type);
          }
        }
  },
```

Pass it to the child element:

```
 <my-dynamic_element 
          animal='{{animal}}'>
  </my-dynamic_element>
```

Use it inside the child element:

```
 domReady: function() {
      console.log('in Dynamic:');
      this.animal.displayType();
  },
```

Note, when passing objects warp the attributes in single quotes:

```
 obj_attr='{{obj_attr}}'
```

Comment: My parent page is not a polymer element.It is just a html page.I am binding my polymer element from a javascript page. How to bind it dynamically here.I have already imported my-element in my html page even though I am getting [Object object]

Comment: Outside polymer-elements use: <template is="auto-binding"> : https://blog.polymer-project.org/howto/2014/09/11/template-is-autobinding/

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. I had to update Polymer also before doing this.